# Get ID of a Parent Folder in a Document Library

Tags: sharepoint-online

For the following folder structure, let's say I am viewing documents under "Level 2 Folder", I would like to get ID for "Level 2 Folder" using JavaScript, either using JSCOM or Rest API for SharePoint Online.

```
-Level 1 Folder
--Level 2 Folder
---Level 3 Document
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be very simple.

```
ctx.ListData.FolderId
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the below REST API endpoint to get the Folder Item ID,

```
_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('" + ctx.rootFolder + "')/listitemallfields/id"
```

Example:

```
http://sharepointsite/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/Library/Level 1 Folder/Level 2 Folder')/listitemallfields/id
```

Comment: This worked though my answer seems to be simpler but I am not sure how reliable it is.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below url for REST call

```
var restUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('" + ctx.rootFolder + "'/UniqueId"
```

Comment: This gets me the UniqueID which is a GUID but not the List Item ID which is a integer. I need the integer List Item ID